# NotificationCenter observe problems

Tags: swift, nsnotificationcenter, notificationcenter

Having some trouble with the swift3 -> swift4 conversion. This was my original code before the conversion:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(DataCollectionViewController.playerItemDidReachEnd), name: Notification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: carVideoPlayer?.currentItem)

_ = observe(notificationName: Notification.Name.UIApplicationDidBecomeActive) {
    _ in
    if recorder.tripRunning {
        self.carVideoPlayer?.play()
    }
}

_ = observe(notificationName: Notification.Name.UIApplicationDidEnterBackground) {
    _ in
    self.carVideoPlayer?.pause()
}
_ = observe(notificationName: .tripStopped) {
    _ in
    self.carVideoPlayer?.pause()
}
```

After converting, I'm getting syntax problems with the lines calling observe; "Generic parameter 'Value' could not be inferred". Anyone know the reason for this? Swift 4's compiler said that the argument labels were extraneous and that the closure type expects 2 arguments.
This is the code after converting:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(DataCollectionViewController.playerItemDidReachEnd), name: Notification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: carVideoPlayer?.currentItem)


    _ = observe(Notification.Name.UIApplicationDidBecomeActive) {
        _,_ in
        if recorder.tripRunning {
            self.carVideoPlayer?.play()
        }
    }

    _ = observe(Notification.Name.UIApplicationDidEnterBackground) {
        _,_ in
        self.carVideoPlayer?.pause()
    }
    _ = observe(.tripStopped) {
        _,_ in
        self.carVideoPlayer?.pause()
    }
```

Comment: What is this `observer` function you are trying to use?

Comment: public func observe(notificationName: String, block: (NSNotification) -> ())

http://swift.logdown.com/posts/308379-notifications-in-swift

Comment: Update your question with your complete `observe` function. Don't post code in comments.